# Why isn't my JButton appearing on my JFrame?

Tags: java

I am not sure why my JButton is not appearing on my JFrame. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class tttMain extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2294426281847625986L;

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
    private static ArrayList<JButton> buttonList;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        //vertical lines
        g.drawLine(150, 65, 150, 340);
        g.drawLine(260, 65, 260, 340);
        //horizontal lines
        g.drawLine(65, 150, 340, 150);
        g.drawLine(65, 260, 340, 260);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setContentPane(new tttMain());
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        b1 = new JButton("Hi Stack Overflow!");

        b1.setBounds(85, 85, 65, 65);

        panel.add(b1);


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Can somebody help me out? I have used JButtons before with no problem, so I don't know why this doesn't work. this is my first time using the Graphics class so maybe that could be apart of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the "symptom" of your problem is caused by `panel.setLayout(null);`, but the root of your problem is a mis-understanding into how component layout works.

Layout managers do a lot of important work and you should be taking the time to learn and understand them.

`JPanel`, by default, uses a `FlowLayout`.  `tttMain` (which, by the way, violates the community naming conventions ;)) extends from `JPanel`, since you never change the layout manager, it's using a `FlowLayout`.

You then add a `JPanel` to it, which has had it's layout set to `null`.  This means that it is no longer providing sizing hints to it's parent - so it will be laid out with a size of `0x0`, which leads us to your underlying problem.

The short story - don't use `null` layouts.  The long story, you may consider using a different approach, maybe taking advantage of a `BorderLayout` and adding both the `tttMain` () and the `JPanel` with the button to it, as an idea

I'd strongly recommend spending some time going through and understanding [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. I don't have much experience with "real world" programming as I have only begun to learn java from a Computer Science course at my school.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem using null layout's however I always specify the minimumSize and maximumSize. 
Using absolute layout also, doesn't re-size well. and can cause some problem's down the road.
I also use WindowBuilder in eclipse because, you should probably not be doing it by hand.